# How can I $fwrite a negative integer number in a file?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an ALU in Verilog, and I want to write the ALU's output into a file.  I am using the following code:

```
$fwrite(File,"La salida es: %d",uut.ALUOutput);
```

My output vector has a size of 32 bits (signed). The operation is correct, but when `ALUOutput` is a negative number, in the file, the output is saved like integer unsigned.

For example, in the file for a negative number, I obtained the following incorrect representation:

```
4294967264
```

But, I want to obtain the following result:

```
-32
```

How can I write a negative number in a file?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$signed` (IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 11.7 *Signed expressions*):

```
module tb;

integer f1;
reg signed [31:0] ALUOutput;

initial begin
    f1 = $fopen("foo.txt", "w");
    ALUOutput = -32;
    $fwrite(f1, "ALUOutput: %d",  $signed(ALUOutput));
    $fdisplay(f1);
    ALUOutput = 32;
    $fwrite(f1, "ALUOutput: %d",  $signed(ALUOutput));
    $fdisplay(f1);
    $fclose(f1);
end

endmodule
```

`foo.txt`:

```
ALUOutput:         -32
ALUOutput:          32
```